# Optimizing with Constraint in R (objective function in optim evaluates to length 0 not 1)

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I want to minimize this function with constraint
[image]

The step is **I need to find t(i) that optimize (minimize) the E(TC)**

Here are my codes for n=3 and want to minimize E(TC) with the optimum t(i) ,i =1,2,3. Note that t(1) must equal to zero, and with constraint t(2)<t(3)<T

```
OptExp<-function(te){
  mu=0.001299059
  sigm=0.00006375925
  D=80
  K=500
  F=0.7
  T=40
  Po=-0.0208801593
  mu=0.001299059
  
  n=3
  t=as.vector(n,mode="numeric")
  P1=as.vector(n,mode="numeric")
  P2=as.vector(n,mode="numeric")
  Pt1=as.vector(n,mode="numeric")
  Pt2=as.vector(n,mode="numeric")

  for (i in 2:(n)){
  t[1]=0
  t[i]=te[i-1]}
  
  for (i in 1:n){
  if(i!=n){
  P1[i]=Po*exp((mu+(sigm^2)/2)*t[i])*D*(t[i+1]-t[i])
  P2[i]=(1/2)*Po*exp((mu+(sigm^2)/2)*t[i])*F*D*(t[i+1]-t[i])^2}
  else {
  P1[i]=Po*exp((mu+(sigm^2)/2)*t[i])*D*(T-t[i])
  P2[i]=(1/2)*Po*exp((mu+(sigm^2)/2)*t[i])*F*D*(T-t[i])^2}}
  
  Pt1=sum(P1)
  Pt2=sum(P2)
  
  E=n*K+Pt1+Pt2
  
  #constraint
  if (t[3]<T & t[1]<t[2] & t[2]<t[3]){
  return(E)}
}

optmz=optim(c(3,5),fn=OptExp)
```

But the result is

```
Error in optim(c(3, 5), fn = OptExp) : 
  objective function in optim evaluates to length 0 not 1
```

Anyone knows what is wrong from my code?

*ps: I also try with consrtOptim

```
  n=2
  t=as.vector(n,mode="numeric")
  t[1]=0
  
OptExp<-function(te){
  mu=0.001299059
  sigm=0.00006375925
  D=80
  K=500
  F=0.7
  T=40
  Po=-0.0208801593
  mu=0.001299059
  
  P1=as.vector(n,mode="numeric")
  P2=as.vector(n,mode="numeric")
  Pt1=as.vector(n,mode="numeric")
  Pt2=as.vector(n,mode="numeric")
  
  for (i in 2:(n)){
  t[1]=0
  t[i]=te[i-1]}
  
  for (i in 1:n){
  if(i!=n){
  P1[i]=Po*exp((mu+(sigm^2)/2)*t[i])*D*(t[i+1]-t[i])
  P2[i]=(1/2)*Po*exp((mu+(sigm^2)/2)*t[i])*F*D*(t[i+1]-t[i])^2}
  else {
  P1[i]=Po*exp((mu+(sigm^2)/2)*t[i])*D*(T-t[i])
  P2[i]=(1/2)*Po*exp((mu+(sigm^2)/2)*t[i])*F*D*(T-t[i])^2}}
  
  Pt1=sum(P1)
  Pt2=sum(P2)
  
  E=n*K+Pt1+Pt2
  return(E)
}

lb=t[n-1]
u1=cbind(c(1,-1));u1
c1=c(lb,-40)
init=c(3)
value<-constrOptim(init,f=OptExp,ui=u1,ci=c1,grad=NULL)
```

note that the constraint for n=2 is t(1)=0<t(2)<T=40

and it returns

```
one-dimensional optimization by Nelder-Mead is unreliable:
use "Brent" or optimize() directly
```

Comment: You cannot just return nothing in the OptExp function. Where did you get that idea from? You may want to look into the function: `constrOptim` which allows you to specify linear inequality constraints.

Comment: I have tried using constrOptim, please look at my edited question.. Any idea? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just simply following the instructions in the error messages (no thinking required) leads to:

```
  value<-constrOptim(init,f=OptExp,ui=u1,ci=c1,grad=NULL,
               method="Brent",lower=0,upper=40)
```

and

```
  OptExp<-function(te,...){
```

For more than one `t` use method="Nelder-Mead" (or better BFGS)